# Add two html to GeckoFx

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I wrote an app in windows form and use GeckoFx in it.

I added successfully a square shape (from an .html file) to GeckoFx using:

```
gecko.Navigate(pathToSquareHtml);
```

Now I want to show a small circle on square using:

```
gecko.Navigate(pathToCircleHtml);
```

But the square shape is removed and only circle is shown.

How can I show both shapes using GeckoFx?

**Edit**

The location of the circle can be variable. And both shapes (square and circle) are clickable to get data from them.

Comment: You need to have both shapes in a single html content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both shapes in a single html content, for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:blue;" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="fill:red;"/>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The edit doesn't make a difference in the answer. In fact the whole point of the answer is in using a single html file rather than using different html files. If you have questions about how to satisfy *The location of the circle can be variable. And both shapes (square and circle) are clickable to get data from them.* then ask a new question as it's not a Windows Forms question and it's more a SVG question.

Comment: I only want to say that I inserted the GeckoFx in a winform.

Comment: Based upon your answer, I found a new solution and combined two html in one html. Both are clickable.

Comment: Cool :) ‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​‫​